Restrict log output using ESAPI with spring boot
I am trying to restrict logging that ESAPI produces. I would like to disable printing of event type and method name.
I am using following:

ESAPI version 2.5.3.1
spring boot 3.2.5
Java 1.17 (Amazon Corretto jdk17.0.10_7)
slf4j 2.0.12

In ESAPI.properties there are following settings:

ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
Logger.ApplicationName=
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
Logger.LogApplicationName=false
Logger.LogServerIP=false
Logger.UserInfo=false
Logger.ClientInfo=false

I am using \resources\logback-spring.xml with the following formatting specifications (it did not  change before and after the implementation of ESAPI):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logfiles" />
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss"/>
    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1}): %msg%n%throwable               
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/ta-event-bridge_${bySecond}.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>   
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/eb-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

</configuration>

Before the usage of ESAPI I had logged following lines:
2024-05-03 15:14:13,912 INFO c.t.m.e.h.SecurityHandler [pool-3-thread-1] Successfully transformed security update #1
2024-05-03 15:14:13,912 INFO c.t.m.e.h.SecurityHandler [pool-3-thread-1] Successfully transformed security update #2
2024-05-03 15:14:13,912 INFO c.t.m.e.h.SecurityHandler [pool-3-thread-1] Successfully transformed security update #3
After implementing ESAPI:
2024-05-29 10:04:07,156 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1]   o.o.e.l.s.Slf4JLogLevelHandlers$3: [SECURITY SUCCESS -> /com.microservices.eventbridge.handlers.SecurityHandler] Successfully transformed security update #1
2024-05-29 10:04:07,156 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] o.o.e.l.s.Slf4JLogLevelHandlers$3: [SECURITY SUCCESS -> /com.microservices.eventbridge.handlers.SecurityHandler] Successfully transformed security update #2
2024-05-29 10:04:07,156 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] o.o.e.l.s.Slf4JLogLevelHandlers$3: [SECURITY SUCCESS -> /com.microservices.eventbridge.handlers.SecurityHandler] Successfully transformed security update #3
Ideally I would like to have the same output like before I implemented ESAPI.
So, I wonder if it is possible to:
1. disable printing of EvenType->className e.g. [SECURITY SUCCESS -> /com.microservices.eb.handlers.SecurityHandler]?
2. have the class name logged like before e.g. instead of o.o.e.l.s.Slf4JLogLevelHandlers$3 to have c.t.m.e.h.SecurityHandler?
